# How to delete item from spinner added via entries in layout xml?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, spinner

I have this array  in my strings.xml :

```
<string-array name="lst_addressTypes">
    <item>FISCAL</item>
    <item>NAP</item>
    <item>SUCURSAL</item>
    <item>ALMACEN</item>
    <item>OFICINA</item>
    <item>OTRO</item>
</string-array>
```

And I have this Spinner in my layout XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cboTipoDireccion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/lst_addressTypes" />
```

And I want to delete some items programmatically.

I tried to do this like:
 `spinnerObject.removeViewAt(0)`
but this threw an `InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add  `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>` for entries in your activity.

**Adding:**

```
    List<String> entriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    // add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        String[] entries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lst_addressTypes);     
        entriesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(entries));

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cboTipoDireccion);
        ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entriesList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    }
```

**Removing:**

```
 entriesList.remove(0);
 spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```